# Have a lot of strange connections to postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I have deployed postgres database on google cloud by kubernetes. I only use DataGrip to run some sql scripts and test the database. I haven't run any additional services or programs.

After I left the database for one day I have the strange logs

```
2024-02-25 12:08:42.990 UTC [14890] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-25 12:08:48.270 UTC [14892] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-25 12:08:48.270 UTC [14892] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-25 12:08:51.549 UTC [14894] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-25 12:08:51.549 UTC [14894] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-25 12:08:54.498 UTC [14896] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-25 12:08:54.498 UTC [14896] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-25 12:08:59.547 UTC [14897] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-25 12:08:59.547 UTC [14897] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-25 12:09:03.284 UTC [14898] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-25 12:09:03.284 UTC [14898] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-25 12:09:07.893 UTC [14899] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-25 12:09:07.893 UTC [14899] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-25 12:09:14.411 UTC [14901] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-25 12:09:14.411 UTC [14901] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-25 12:09:18.038 UTC [14902] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-25 12:09:18.038 UTC [14902] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-25 12:09:23.023 UTC [14903] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-25 12:09:23.023 UTC [14903] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-25 12:09:24.523 UTC [14904] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-25 12:09:24.523 UTC [14904] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-25 12:09:28.164 UTC [14905] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-25 12:09:28.164 UTC [14905] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-25 12:09:32.411 UTC [14907] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I also had the same situation when I deployed database on DigitalOcean by docker.

The YAML file

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: database-sfs
spec:
  serviceName: database-srv
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: database
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: database
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: postgres-port
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: <my-password-here>
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-data
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: postgres-data
      spec:
        storageClassName: manual
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteMany
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: database-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: database
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: database
    protocol: TCP
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
```

Of cource I also created persistent volume.

If I try to connect the database, it works and all data are saved.

It seems like an attack but I haven't published any database credentials.
What could this be and how to solve this?

Comment: If your database is directly accessible from the internet you can expect a constant stream of random login attempts. Unless you really know what you are doing and have a good reason not to, stick a firewall in front of it and only allow access from your application's IPs

Comment: It is an attack, unsuccessful as far as we can see.  If your passwords are unguessable and don't get leaked, then there is nothing to solve.

Comment: This `host all all all scram-sha-256` is not a good line to have in [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for a machine having open access from the Internet. Read the information at the `pg_hba.conf` link and use that information to restrict access as step one. Step two would be to do as @RichardHuxton suggests and put a firewall in front of the database.

Comment: Yeah, I just use the database for study and don't really care about data. When I used DigitalOcean I configured `pg_hba.conf` and the problem was solved. I just wanted to understand the problem and whether this is a usual situation for unsafe databases. So thank you.

Comment: @jjanes - Except Google charges for network traffic and allowing bad actors to attempt connection attempts will cost money. I have seen thousand-dollar bills as hackers try to brute force passwords.